How can I use VBA in Excel to replace a worksheet with a hidden one each time the workbook is opened?
I have a workbook with one visible worksheet that's essentially a form that will be input to by a user.
I also have one hidden worksheet which is identical to the visible one.
I wish to use VBA to have the visible worksheet replaced by a copy of the hidden one each time the workbook is reopened. Basically if there are any changes to the visible one by the user, when opening the file it should be replaced by the original version (the hidden one) again.
I've tried worksheets.copy but just can't figure it out properly.
Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook 


What are the names of these worksheets?

This code will overwrite the sheet named Visible with the contents of the sheet named hidden:
Sheets("Hidden").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Visible").Range("A1")

You can put code in the Workbook_Open() sub to have it run when the workbook is opened.

Thankyou! Will that also copy over conditional formatting and sheet view etc?

Replace Visible Worksheet with Hidden
Workbook Module (ThisWorkbook)
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ResetThisWorkbook
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1
Sub ResetThisWorkbook()
' Replaces a visible worksheet with a copy of a hidden worksheet.
' The (visible) copy will have the same index, name and code name
' as the initially visible worksheet.
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reset Workbook"
    Const WORKSHEETS_COUNT As Long = 2
    Const MSG_SHEETS_COUNT As String = "There are too many worksheets!"
    Const MSG_VISIBILITY As String = "All worksheets are visible!"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Exit if too many worksheets.
    If wb.Worksheets.Count > WORKSHEETS_COUNT Then
        MsgBox MSG_SHEETS_COUNT, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim ws As Worksheet, vws As Worksheet, hws As Worksheet
    Dim hVisible As Long, vName As String, vCodeName As String
    
    ' Reference the worksheets and store the necessary properties in variables.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then ' checking for visible...
            Set vws = ws
            vName = ws.Name
            vCodeName = ws.CodeName
        Else ' ... allowing 'Hidden' and 'VeryHidden'
            Set hws = ws
            hVisible = ws.Visible
        End If
    Next ws
         
    ' Exit if no hidden worksheet.
    If hws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox MSG_VISIBILITY, vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
         
    'Debug.Print vws.Index, vws.Name, vws.CodeName
    'Debug.Print hws.Index, hws.Name, hws.CodeName
    
    ' Create and reference a (visible) copy of the hidden worksheet
    ' i.e. the new visible worksheet.
    hws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    hws.Copy Before:=vws
    hws.Visible = hVisible
    Set ws = vws.Previous
    
    ' Delete the old visible worksheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
        vws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Rename the new visible worksheet.
    ws.Name = vName
    wb.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.CodeName) _
        .Properties("_CodeName").Value = vCodeName

End Sub

